# How to access the source data when manipulating/updating fitted models

Tags: r, functional-programming, regression, nse

I'm trying to write some functions to ease refitting multiple models, but find it painful, as R is unable to locate proper `data`, when it plunges deeper into evaluation tree. 
Despite an effort was made to store the formula environment inside the model, I guess there's really no way to unambiguously point to the raw data object. 
This becomes even harder for fitting survival curves using `survfit`, where no `terms` object is being stored inside.

Do I really need to retype the data/formula as a parameter each time?

Example:

```
# model-fitting wrapper function
fn <- function(fn_formula, fn_data) {
    lm(formula = fn_formula, data = fn_data)
}
# specify exemplary data and formula
data <- data.frame(
    y = rnorm(100),
    x1 = rnorm(100),
    x2 = rnorm(100))
formula <- y ~ x1

# try to create and update the fit with different parameters
fn_fit <- fn(formula, data)
update(fn_fit, ~ x2)
# Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'fn_data' not found
terms(fn_fit) %>% attr('.Environment')
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
terms(fn_fit$model) %>% attr('.Environment')
# <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
getCall(fn_fit)
# lm(formula = fn_formula, data = fn_data)
```

Answer (score 3):

The variable that stores the data should be in the same scope for both the `lm()` and `update()` with the same name. Not sure what you are really trying to accomplish, bit if you want a function that creates a signature you can use in the global environment, you can do something like this would work

```
fn <- function(fn_formula, fn_data) {
  do.call("lm", list(fn_formula, data=substitute(fn_data)))
}
fn_fit <- fn(formula, data)
update(fn_fit, ~ x2)
```

Otherwise if you really wanted to capture that variable in the local function scope, you can create a helper to fun update in the correct environment.

```
fn <- function(fn_formula, fn_data) {
  environment(fn_formula) <- environment()
  lm(formula = fn_formula, data = fn_data)
}

fn_update <- function(object, ...) {
  mc<-match.call(definition = update)
  mc[[1]] <- quote(update)
  eval(mc, envir=environment(terms(object)))
}

fn_fit <- fn(formula, data)
fn_update(fn_fit, ~x2)
```

Comment: I'm aware that it's possible to capture the relevant variables with non-standard evaluation and manipulating calls, but I find it unintuitive, as it would require multiple wrappers, assume that the model is not yet fitted using standard call and highly depend on the actual calling stack.

What I really do not understand is the point of maintaining in `terms` the whole calling environment for `y ~ x1` call, which gives no warranty of storing the original data, but may include other memory consuming variables created during the same call of a wrapper function - is there any simple explanation?

Answer (score 1):

When you passed formula, the only items stored in the ['model'] sublist were those that were needed.

```
> names(fn_fit$model)
[1] "y"  "x1"
```

But there's nothing named either 'data' or 'fn_data' in that object. MrFlick second suggestion is more resilient to modifications in the calling tree of frames:

```
> fn <- function(fn_formula, fn_data) {
+   do.call("lm", list(fn_formula, data=substitute(fn_data)))
+ }
> fn_fit <- fn(formula, data); rm(data)  # mess with the calling environment
> update(fn_fit, ~ x2)
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  'data' argument is of the wrong type
```

That error occurred because the R interpreter only found the function named data; if instead you deploy the second option you get:

```
> data <- data.frame(
+     y = rnorm(100),
+     x1 = rnorm(100),
+     x2 = rnorm(100))

> fn <- function(fn_formula, fn_data) {
+   environment(fn_formula) <- environment()
+   lm(formula = fn_formula, data = fn_data)
+ }
> 
> fn_update <- function(object, ...) {
+   mc<-match.call(definition = update)
+   mc[[1]] <- quote(update)
+   eval(mc, envir=environment(terms(object)))
+ }

> 
> fn_fit <- fn(formula, data) ; rm(data)
> fn_update(fn_fit, ~x2)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x2, data = fn_data)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x2  
    0.01117     -0.13004
```